# Use of unresolved identifier 'PresentationButton'

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, swiftui

Use of unresolved identifier 'PresentationButton', is there any new Class introduced for 'PresentationButton'?

Did anyone have used the 'PresentationButton' in their code. I would like to open an view on click of the image or content frame.

```
PresentationButton(destination: ContentView()) {
    CourseView()
}
```

I did tried to find out the documentation in apple developer's website but I do not see any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not showing the view modally (in which case `.sheet` is the way to go), the preferred way in Xcode 11 beta 5 is using `NavigationLink`.

```
NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
            Text("show ContentView")
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

PresentationButton is deprecated. If you want to present a sheet use something like below.

```
struct ModalExample: View {
    @State var show = false

    var detail: ModalView {
        return ModalView()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Present") {
                self.show = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $show, content: { ModalView() })
    }
}

struct ModalView : View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Modal")
            Button("Close") {
                self.presentationMode.value.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```